# Java - dynamically build textview reference

Tags: java, android

New Android/Java coder. Trying to replicate in Android app a project I built in MS-Access.

I have a layout with similar named TextViews, like text10, text12, etc. In MS-Access I can dynamically build those names with collection referencing:

```
For X = 10 To 15
    Me.Controls("text" & X) = Null
Next
```

There is no array required. So looking for structure in java that can accomplish the same functionality.

I want to dynamically set background color of multiple TextView based on two inputs. One is to build TextView reference and the other is a state indicator that will determine color.

Here is one procedure calling setSubColor:

```
public void Clear(MenuItem mi) {
    puz.setText("");
    sol.setText("");
    for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        setSubColor(aryA[i].charAt(0), 0);
```

What I have so far for setSubColor:

```
public void setSubColor (char c, int i) {
    TextView v = (TextView) >>>dynamically reference v using name built with ("tv" + c)
    if (i == 0) {v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);}
    else {v.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);}
```

Comment: Use an array or list of elements. Even if you could do it the way you are talking about, it is a terrible idea. Don't follow access programming styles in java; there is a reason no one uses VBA anymore

Comment: Maybe someday I will learn this but for now cannot find clear explanation of how to fill array with TextViews defined in xml layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the res id from the res name at runtime. So if your textview had name "text1", you could get the integer id by using:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("text1", "string", getPackageName());
TextView view = findViewById(id);
```

But do so only as a last resort, it's error prone, slow and somewhat of an anti pattern.

EDIT by OP: No matter what the name argument is always returns 0 but marked as answer because it led to the following code that works exactly as I want, anti-pattern or not.

```
TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tv" + c, "id", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `TextView` `Id` field use its `Tag` field.
`String tag = (String)textView.getTag()` and `textView.setTag(Object tag)` with `tag instanceof String`

then you can find the `TextView` by `Tag`

Comment: Are you serious? textView is just a variable name, obviously you have to use your own

Comment: Yes, I understand that and after getting that error tried to declare and initiate but that did not work either. What would I initiate it to? Is moot now as Timo Ohr reply solved the issue. But thank you for the effort, most appreciated.